# Cannot use std::iota with std::set

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, stl

I'd like to create a set of a range of numbers: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ...
The following code fails to compile:

```
std::set<int> s;
std::iota(s.begin(), s.end(), 0);
```

with the following error message:

```
error C3892: '_First' : you cannot assign to a variable that is const
```

The compiler is VC++2012. The same code works fine for a vector. How should I use it with a set?

**UPDATE**

I can see now that my code is meaningless, because there's no set size specified.

Here are some more details about my problem.

I have a set containing SOME numbers from [0, N] range. In my application I need to calculate set difference many times for such sets. N is fixed.

Let's say `N = 5` and the first set is `s1 = {0, 3, 4}`. I need to calculate set difference `{0, 1, 2, 3, 4} \ {0, 3, 4} == {1, 2}`. This operation should be performed quite often for different sets, so I thought that I could create a set with all numbers (`{0, 1, 2, 3, 4}` in this case) and use `std::set_difference` to calculate those differences.

Comment: That would be a no-op for an `std::vector`. What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To solve your actual problem: `std::set_difference` has less to do with `std::set` than you might expect. You can use any pair of iterators as the first two parameters of `set_difference` provided they return the values in order. There is no particular benefit in it being a set.

So for example the begin/end iterators of a `std::vector` containing the values 0 ... n-1 in order would work, or a pair of `boost::counting_iterator`:

```
std::set result;
std::set_difference(
    boost::counting_iterator<int>(0), boost::counting_iterator<int>(n),
    s1.begin(), s1.end(),
    std::inserter(result, result.end())
);
```

The output doesn't need to be a set either, you could just as well use a `vector` with `back_inserter`.

To solve what you asked: it doesn't make sense to try to use `iota` on a set. `iota` changes the values contained in a range, by assigning new values to them. You can't assign to the values in a `set`.

If you want a set containing the numbers `0 ... n-1`, then:

```
std::set<int> s;
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    s.insert(s.end(), i);
}
```

If someone told you that loops are for wusses and real C++ programmers use algorithms, then you can get `iota` involved if you really want:

```
std::set<int> s;
{
    std::vector<int> vec(n);
    std::iota(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 0);
    s.insert(vec.begin(), vec.end());
}
```

Unfortunately that's kind of inefficient. So if you love algorithms so much that you might as well marry them, then you can reach outside the standard libraries:

```
std::set<int> s(boost::counting_iterator<int>(0), boost::counting_iterator<int>(n));
```

Comment: "So if you love algorithms so much that you might as well marry them, then you can reach outside the standard libraries". Lol, +1 for truth and entertainment

Comment: Why not add the answer too: the one where you pass counting_iterator directly to set_difference…

Comment: how about `std::ranges::iota_view(N)`?

Answer (score 4):

A slightly inelegant alternative:

```
set<int> s;
generate_n(inserter(s, s.end()), 10, [&]{ return s.size(); });
```

Comment: I'm not sure about that `static` variable, what happens when you run the code twice? (Not copy-and pasted, which would be OK because identical lambda expressions are still different types. I mean executing the same lines twice). You could just do `int i = 0;` on the previous line, though, and capture it by reference.

Comment: I don't think anything is too tricky, given that the object of the exercise is to perversely avoid the shorter, clearer loop ;-) I'd want to check, though, that the standard for `generate_n` guarantees the order of execution of the function relative to the assignments. There's no earthly reason anyone should implement `generate_n` to "read ahead", but if it's not forbidden then the code's not strictly correct. `parallel_generate_n`, anyone?

Comment: The wording seems to strongly imply it but doesn't appear to explicitly guarantee it: "The second algorithm invokes the function object gen and assigns the return value of gen through all the iterators in the range [first,first + n)"

Answer (score 1):

A set differs from a vector in that a vector has an association from an index to the value stored at that index, while a set has only information whether a value is in the set.  So assigning values to the set element is nonsensical -- and the way to enforce it is that the elements in the set are constant.

The equivalent way to do it would be something like removing the values you do not want in the set (the "old" values in the case of the vector), then iterate through the values you do want to store (with itoa it would be a sequence of increasing values) and add them one-by-one to the set.