# C++ routine to place all short into a set

Tags: c++

It should be possible, since the number of `short int`s is less than the `max_size()` of an `std::set<short int>`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <limits.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    std::set<short int> mySet;
    std::cout << "Max size of mySet is " << mySet.max_size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Number of short ints is " << pow(2.0, double(sizeof(short int) * CHAR_BIT)); 
    return 0;
}
```

outputs

```
Max size of mySet is 4294967295
Number of short ints is 65536
```

Now, what I'd like to do is place all `short int`s into a set, meaning I need a routine to iterate over all `short int`s. If possible, I would like a general routine for iterating over all elements of a given type. Anyone have some insight?

Comment: Why do you need this? I mean, what purpose could it have?

Comment: so loop through 0 - 65535 and add each value to your set.

Comment: Iterate over all the short ints inserting each one into your set.

Comment: `std::numeric_limits` gives you the lowest and highest possible values of the type; from there it's a trivial loop.

Comment: Read up on [`std::numeric_limits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits) and the `for` loop.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Why does everything need to have a purpose?

Comment: It doesn't. But computer programs without a purpose are quite pointless. I was just trying to figure out what you are trying to solve here, because there could have been better alternatives.

Comment: @DonaldKnuth: If you want someone to do it for you for free, it needs to have a purpose. Also, impersonating famous individuals in our field is frowned upon.

Comment: Actually, this is quite similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19529527/218597), albeit with a different range.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: with a template function to accept other decimal types.

```
template<typename T>
std::unique_ptr<set<T>> CreateSet() 
{
    unique_ptr<std::set<T>> mySet(new std::set<T>());
    for( T i = std::numeric_limits<T>::min(); i < std::numeric_limits<T>::max(); i++ )
    {
      mySet->insert( i );
    }
    mySet->insert(std::numeric_limits<T>::max());
    //std::cout << mySet->size();
    return mySet;
}

int main() {

    auto s = CreateSet<short int>();
    // ...
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks commenters for the fixes

Note: it is unclear why you would want this, or even why you want to use a set (and not a vector) when uniqueness is guaranteed by construction.

Comment: Your set will be missing one value.

Comment: Who do you need to do the cast inside your loop?

Comment: Now your loop doesn't terminate. This is one place you probably don't want `auto`.

Comment: If you're going to make a function for it, maybe you should return something from the function?

Comment: edited, but still don't know what th OP wants to do with that.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun:

```
template <typename T>
void fill_all_values( std::set<T> &s ) {
    T t = T();
    do s.insert( t++ ); while ( t != T() );
}
```

One more fun solution:

```
template <typename T>
void fill_all_values_2( std::set<T> &s ) {
    typedef std::set<T>::size_type size_type;
    size_type t_max = (size_type( 1 ) << (CHAR_BIT*sizeof(T))) - 1;
    for ( size_type i = 0; i < t_max; ++i )
        s.insert( *reinterpret_cast<T*>(&i) );
    s.insert( *reinterpret_cast<T*>(&t_max) );
}
```

Comment: To tell the truth, the problem is not clear for me. What types do you expect it should work for?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your goal can be achieved by using a loop as follows.

```
for( int i = 0; i < 65536; i++ )
{
  mySet.insert( (short int)i );
}
```

The different type for actual iteration should be used to avoid overflow. However, I totally second the comments above; why would you need such a set? I would strongly suggest a different approach.