# Which is faster for checking whether a condition is true?

Tags: c++, optimization

(1)

```
if (!cond)
```

or

(2)

```
if (cond == false)
```

Seems like I see a lot of people using (1). But isn't that less than optimal? In C++, an `if (...)` statement evaluates true so long as whatever is in the parentheses is a non-zero value. So, in (1), what has to happen is

- Do a logical NOT on `cond`
- Check whether the result is non-zero (whether any bits are on)

whereas, in (2), all that has to happen is

- Check whether `cond` is zero (whether all bits are off)

Now, the time taken to check whether all bits are off will always be greater than or equal to the time to check whether any bits are on. Therefore, the question is whether the time to perform a logical NOT makes up for any difference, on average.

Which should I use to optimize my code?

Comment: If you care, you should be in a position to measure the difference (otherwise, you shouldn't care.) So, measure and see. But check whether the generated assembly code is different first.

Comment: Compilers are pretty smart when it comes to primitive types. If either way were faster, the compiler would know and use that. If you're talking operator overrides, they're not even guaranteed to be the same.

Comment: Have you benchmarked it?

Comment: There is more to life than optimal execution speed. C++ devs values readability and intent. Trust the compiler and write something I can read.

Comment: Also, your reasoning is flawed -- the first requires (syntactically) evaluating cond, then evaluating its opposite (and taking that as the condition's value). The second requires evaluating cond, then comparing it to a constant, and taking the result of the comparison as the condition value. In both cases, the compiler can almost always optimize away everything to a single conditional jump instruction.

Comment: This isn't the code that's worth spending time worrying about. Any compiler since 1980 should do the right thing for you in either case. You can measure and inspect the output to validate, but even if you have a backwards compiler you need to consider both it and the target architecture to consider. (Of course if `cond` has operator overloading then either case could do anything)

Comment: Why do people downvote this question so much? It is obvious that the OP has completely wrong ideas about optimisation and compiler cleverness, but his question is very clear and shows some research effort, and I thought that's what voting is for.

Comment: Most of your questions suggest that you are pre-occupied with the wrong kind of optimization. I suggest you listen to the advice you are given by everybody. If you have evidence that one way is faster than the other, then please come back and ask why. Otherwise, everybody is going to say the same thing: "premature optimization", "you're optimizing the wrong thing"...

Comment: @ChristianHackl What research effort? At the very least the OP should've looked at generated assembly, or done some benchmarking.

Comment: "We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil. Yet we should not pass up our opportunities in that critical 3%. A good programmer will not be lulled into complacency by such reasoning, he will be wise to look carefully at the critical code; but only after that code has been identified" — Donald E. Knuth

(Sorry couldn't resist to post that qoute.)

Comment: Just checked the OP's name. I think we're being had. :) (thanks for cluing me in, src).

Comment: @Praetorian: by those standards, almost nobody should be allowed to ask a question here. With enough research on your own, you can find out the answer to *anything* without ever asking on SO. As I see the question, the OP obviously gave the issue quite some thought.

Comment: @dlf: Damn it, you're right. I'm not used to trolls here on SO, so the troll detector in my brain seems to have been turned off :(

Comment: @ChristianHackl You're not alone. "Sufficiently advanced incompetence is indistinguishable from malice."

Comment: @dlf: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23937893/c-routine-to-place-all-short-into-a-set#comment36870682_23937893

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tested it with `clang -O3`:

```
int main () {
    int i;
    cin >> i;

    if (i == 0)
    return -1;
}
```

Produces

```
leaq    4(%rsp), %rsi
movl    $_ZSt3cin, %edi
callq   _ZNSirsERi
cmpl    $1, 4(%rsp)
sbbl    %eax, %eax
popq    %rdx
ret
```

while

```
int main () {
    int i;
    cin >> i;

    if (!i)
    return -1;
}
```

produces

```
leaq    4(%rsp), %rsi
movl    $_ZSt3cin, %edi
callq   _ZNSirsERi
cmpl    $1, 4(%rsp)
sbbl    %eax, %eax
popq    %rdx
ret
```

So no difference at all.

Comment: does other O's do the same?

Comment: @SampoSarrala  Who cares?  Seriously.   I write software that is currently handling 24 million transactions a second. We would never bother to try to "optimize" the source code at this level -- its a waste of programmer time that could be better spent profiling the fully optimized (by the compiler) code to find the real hot spots.

Comment: @DaleWilson no one cares if you are not working with time critical rtos code... it's not about optimization here.

Answer (score 1):

Optimization is not an issue.   Any compiler worth using will generate exactly the same results.    What is an issue is readability of your code.    `if(x == true)` and `if(x == false)` are (to me and many other programmers) much less readable than `if(x)` or `if(!x)`

This is especially true when it evolves into something like `if((a != b) == false)`  Code does have a tendency to evolve over time.

Comment: The only situation I've found comparison to true or false to be quite readable is when I'm really only interested in a very generic boolean "value", for example in a general-purpose storage mechanism.

Comment: I would switch order `if(true == x)` and `if(false == x)` to avoid the common logic mistake of writing `if (x = false)` which is evaluated to `true`

Comment: @NirMH The *common mistake* is not paying attention to compiler warnings, or not having them set at an appropriate level to warn about that.

Comment: @Praetorian - tell that to the poor programmer who worked the night to find this logic bug in a huge program (someone else has written).... i agree you should always compiler with warning level 4... but something this is not the reality (that programmer is me, of course :) )

Comment: @NirMH It doesn't look like you've learned from your experience though :) How exactly does `if (x = false)` evaluate to `true`?

Comment: @NirMH: That decreases readability. In English (or any other language I personally know), you say "if x is true" and not "if true is x". Besides, modern compilers issue a warning if you forget the second `=`. The operand-replacement trick really feels like an 80s thing... :)

Comment: @Praetorian - my case was actually `if (x == 5)` while `x` was an integer - so the expression turned into an assignment which is evaluated as `true`... my learning was always put the literal as l-value of the expression

Comment: @NirMH: `if (x = 5)` produces a warning, too. At least it does so in MSVC 2013 with `/W4`. "warning C4706: assignment within conditional expression".

Answer (score 0):

It seems unlikely that the generated assembly will be different in any modern compiler. In fact, modern compilers will optimize out the entire if statement if they find it's guaranteed to be evaluated along one branch. You can always check the assembly to be sure, of course.

In the end, you should optimize for understandability of your source code in situations like this, rather than optimization post-compilation.

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you my thumb rule for `if` statements design.

I always put in the `evaluated-to-true` block the piece of code i would presume will happen most of the time in my usage.

I believe that the compiler will place the `if` statement `evaluated-to-true` block in the assembly right after the `cmp` command (unless it has more information about your program and then it will optimized it differently).

Modern CPUs will have a slight hit on performance once the `else` block is executed (a branch).

But for the bottom line - if your program is not in a high end performance requirement, you shouldn't care - both are the same. And if you do care, place the common section of code in the `evaluate-to-true` expression block (right after the `if` statement).

I'll spend some time to search for some articles about Compilers/CPU optimization of branches and if i'll find something, i'll edit this answer.